# Java Swing Project - JTable & MVC

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jtable

I'm creating an application in Swing using MVC architecture. But I have some concerns regarding the use of JTable components in MVC architecture. The point is that, I have three columns in a table whose cells contain constant values​​. Also, other columns can be added by clicking on the button, and another button used to calculate constant values into those new created cells.

So, since I now have the three columns with constant values​​, this means that this values need to be initialized into JTable, which sounds like I need to make those constant inside a View class where I have created a JTable component and other components, which is a bad idea, because those constant values I will need to use also for Model class. My alternative was to make the interface with these constants.

I was watching some other simple examples of MVC projects, and I haven't seen anyone yet that implements or create this constants inside a view class. So I'm wonder, should I create an MyTableModel class inside a Model, which extends DefaultTableModel or something like that,
but If I decide to use a model class in a view class, I'm breaking the rule 
"It doesn't know the View exists"?

Has anyone already made ​​a similar project using the MVC pattern and JTable component, or if someone can break up into concepts, like: "On what should I pay more attention", "Where can I create and where not classes"?

Does anyone use Skype or similar form of communication, I don't really mean to being boring, just to have someone to ask some quick and short questions.

Comment: `Does anyone use Skype or similar form of communication` - you can try to use chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Check out this article on how to put a Swing GUI together.  http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=196  It's about a Sudoku Solver, but the steps would be the same when putting any Swing GUI together.

Comment: Values are stored in the `TableModel`; the [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) (view) renders (and optionally edits) the values in the model.

Comment: So it's fine, if i have created an interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple actually if you look into how JTable works (ofcourse if understood your problem right).

To display actual values in different table cells you will have to specify a custom CellRenderer that creates/updates Swing view component based on value from model *every* time cell is displayed/updated(repainted). So table itself doesn't keep/store real values anywhere - it simply updates cell (repaints it) using the values provided by the table model. Such update is performed each time some any changes made to cell: from inside - model value changed, or from outside - table component resized/moved, column resized/moved e.t.c.

So you need to store values only in table model (or even in your own global model and use table model simply as a bridge between table view and your model).

And you can provide values from table model in any way you like - constant values, calculated values, cached values, remotely loaded values - whatever you want. That doesn't affect the table view (unless you create some asynchronous values loading or something like that doesn't fit well with default Swing component models).